# Deploy Test agent failing in VSTS due to WinRM issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm attempting to run a build definition that will ultimately run functional tests on an azure machine, however the build falls over on the deploy test agent step with the following error....

*Error occurred on 'seleniumvm.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com:5986'. Details : 'Connecting to remote server seleniumvm.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.'. For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.*

Full build log can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/711a4036f184de118c9573a11243298b)

This is what my build looks like...

[image]

I was under the assumption the **Azure Resource Group Deployment** task would configure WinRM on my Azure VM. I have that task set to **Configure with WinRM**. This task passes when running the build.

My deploy test agent task details are as follows....

- **Machines:** seleniumvm.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com:5986
- **Admin Login:** SeleniumVM\[username]
- **Admin Password:** [password]
- **Protocol:** HTTPS
- **Test Certicate:** Ticked
- Agent configuration username and password is the same as above

I have ran `winrm quickconfig` and `Enable-PSRemoting Force`, both returning message that WinRM is already setup.

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced this same issue setting up a build machine for VSTS, fix for me was Method 2 here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate

which is to add the following registry key:
In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa**
Right-click **Lsa**, point to **New**, and then click **DWORD** Value.
Type **DisableLoopbackCheck**, and then press ENTER.
Right-click **DisableLoopbackCheck**, and then click **Modify**.
In the **Value** data box, type **1**, and then click OK.

Restart the VM

Comment: Yep that was it. How on earth did you stumble across that?!! Would have taken me a couple of lifetimes to figure that out. Many thanks